# C# App. for sending a visual key "Enter" to a LABVIEW application

Tags: c#, labview

I want develop a C# App. for sending a visual key "Enter" to a LABVIEW application.
This LABVIEW app. has a hot-key (ENTER) to execute function.
So I need execute this function by my C# App.
how I to do that?

I already use 2 methods, but not work

1)

```
IntPtr WindowToFind = FindWindow(null, "title name"); 
PostMessage(WindowToFind, WM_SYSKEYDOWN, VK_ENTER, 0);
```

2)

```
Process p = Process.GetProcessesByName("myApp").FirstOrDefault();
if (p != null)
{
IntPtr h = p.MainWindowHandle;
SetForegroundWindow(h);
SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}");
}
```

thank very much!!

Comment: what about 1st method? what do you return from `FindWindow`? What from `PostMessage`? what is last win32 exception do you get?

Comment: FindWindow and PostMessage are DllImport from "user32.dll".

Comment: We know, you p/invoke them. What are they return?